# MVC4 SelectListItem Selected property

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, dropdownlistfor

I have added a DropDownListFor to my view.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem_ID,Model.ItemsRepository)
```

The list is rendering fine with all the SelectItem objects in my list. However in my SelectItemList there is one SelectItem object that has been set to selected = true. I can place a debug point on the line and I see the property set to true but when the html renders the selected item is never default. It appears to be a bug but I'm not sure. I have tried adding the item manually in a string with another comma no dice. Anyone experiencing the same thing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: in a for helper selected is overridden by the lambda expression.  try setting SelectedItem_ID on the controller (make sure the value matches an item in the list) and see if it is set correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not clearing my model state before returning my view. I added the following in my controller before I cleared my view and it fixed my issues.

ModelState.Clear();

Answer (score 1):

I add here some code I used in one of my projects.

```
private SelectList GetProjectItemType()
        {
            var values = new List<SelectListItem>();
            values.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Project", Text = "Project" });
            values.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Bug", Text = "Bug" });
            values.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Feature", Text = "Feature" });
            values.Add(new SelectListItem() { Value = "Improvement", Text = "Improvement" });
            return new SelectList(values, "Value", "Text", values[1]);
        }
```

The last parameter from SelectList constructor is going to specify which value is going to be selected as the default one.

Hope this is going to help you!

Comment: Okay I have tried both of these methods I can put a break point in the view and I see both the selecteditem object there I assigned using arnoldrob's method and the SelectedItem_ID also on the correct value encase the lambda expression is overriding. It's like all the values are there but the dropdown is not updating. Do I need to clear view state or something to get the new model values in to that dropdown ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItem_ID,Model.ItemsRepository) this is your HTML. I am thinking on antoher problem. For example if your attribute SelectedItem_ID = 2, when view is loaded and in Model.ItemsRepository there is an object with ID = 2 automatically this is going to be the default value in dropdown. So check if there is no value sent from controller side on SelectedItem_ID and that value is going to be defaulted always.

Comment: I had the SelectedItem_ID there without clearing my ModelState the change didn't take place on the view.